# How to place text over image using CSS

Tags: css, z-index

What is the easiest way to place text over an image using CSS (inline preferably), without the use of position:absolute? Also, I am using Bootstrap's grid position containers so everything is responsive. Not sure if that helps anyones answer.

Comment: Show us what have you tried? This is not the place where you will be spoon feeded.

Comment: The easiest way is to use position:absolute ;-) But seriously.. Why don't you want to use position:absolute ?

Comment: I don't expect to be spoon FED. Everything I have tried doesn't work because I don't know how the absolute and relative positions work properly. Hence why I am coming here, I thought this was a place of learning. Apparently not thanks to certain people.

Comment: I want to steer away from absolute because my site is responsive so the text is always in the wrong place when the page size changes

Comment: You *will* need to use positioning...but without some code or a rough idea of what you are trying to do we can't help much. Learning how positioning works is pretty simple really - https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/

Answer (score -1):

Use Z-Indexes. If you're familiar with a 3D grid, this will come natural to you. The higher the Z-Index, the higher priority.

[Here's a nifty little article about it from W3 schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

But here's basically how it works:

```
img {
z-index: 0;
}
.text {
z-index: 1;
}
```

I can understand why you don't wanna use `position: absolute`... sometimes you just want something to be there and stay there :)